# Where condition in oracle request

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, null

I have a a date field who can be `null` in an Oracle Database.

I want to select the row with the highest date. 
But if there is only one row with a `null` date and I use the max clause it will be ignored.

```
SELECT val1, val2 
from T_DER 
WHERE DATE_AP = ( SELECT MAX (DATE_AP) FROM T_DER WHERE AE= 'XXX')
AND (AE= 'XXX');
```

so , in these cases :

- for AE = XXX => row 1 : DATE_AP = 01/01/2015 and row 2 : DATE_AP = 01/02/2016

  - return row 2
- for AE = XXX => row 1 : DATE_AP = 01/01/2015 and row 2 : DATE_AP = null

  - return row 1
- for AE = XXX => row 1 : DATE_AP = null

  - return row 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AE ORDER BY DATE_AP DESC NULLS LAST) as seqnum
      FROM T_DER t
      WHERE AE = 'XXX'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a window/analytic/ranking function, documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).  Basically, it assigns a sequential number to groups of rows, where the groups are defined by the `partition by` clause and the ordering within each group by `order by`.

Comment: Wow its completely beyond understanding for me but it work . Thank you a lot
Can you explain it a little ?

Comment: Also the important part is the `NULLS LAST`, because by default nulls will be on top.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify which Oracle version you're using. Gordon Linoff's answer is of course, correct, and should work on any Oracle version from 8i and above.

If you're using Oracle 12c, though, there's a slightly more elegant way of achieving this result:

```
SELECT   val1, val2 
FROM     t_der 
WHERE    ae = 'XXX'
ORDER BY date_ap DESC
FETCH    FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Thx for answer but i'm under version 11. Sorry for miss that